# Unable to see downloaded videos in specific folder on local network through WIFI

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, video, vlc-media-player

Recently I got a new hard drive and transferred all my data to it, and then made my Videos folder shared over my local network. What has me perplexed is that all my videos are viewable except for a specific folder. This folder has just about 80 files (videos) in it but when I check this folder on my phone through VLC it only shows me 4 videos. I have tried to do "ipconfig /flushdns" thinking that might help somehow and directly going to the folder and sharing it, and I still only see 4 videos. To get it out of the way, the videos used to show up on VLC before I reformatted my PC about a week ago.

I'm quite the novice at networking, so I could really use some help. Any is appreciated.

Comment: What are the permissions on that folder?

Comment: So, you're sharing it from a Windows 10 box via SMB (standard Windows filesharing)? Is there any difference between the visible and invisible files in terms of filename lengths, special characters in the filenames, or video file formats or codecs used?

Comment: Currently there are no permissions for sharing for the specific folder, the entire folder called Videos in which this particular folder is buried under is being shared though. As far as visible and invisible goes, I can see everything on Windows but only 4 files on VLC through my phone. No other differences that I can discern.

Comment: Any ideas on what could be wrong?